# multilingual Silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight

how to make multilingual dynamic Silverlight app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The above MSDN article is indeed good. There are some differences depending upon whether it's an out-of-browser application and a few other gotchas depending upon you need a localised calendar and Right-To-Left support.

This series of articles should give you all the info you kneed to know: [Internationalization/Globalization in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Internationalization-Globalization-in-Silverlight-Part-1-Terminology.aspx).